# How to avoid extracting last specific character in which is part of regex group?

Tags: regex, pcre

Given a command line

```
mycommand --optional-arguments their-values <patternOfInterestWithDirectoryPath> arg1 arg2
```

patternOfInterestWithDirectoryPath can be any of following

```
path/to/dir
/path/to/dir
path/to/dir/
"path/to/dir"
"/path/to/dir"
"path/to/dir/"
```

In any of above the ask is to extract `/path/to/dir` in all cases, where some of them may (or may not )be enclosed with double quotes, and/or may (or may not) have a leading `/`

Following regex does match but it also extracts the lastmost forward slash.

```
 \S*mycommand\s+(?:-\S+\s+)*\"?([^\"]+)\/?\"?.*
```

Attaching a negative lookahead like this does not work

```
 \S*mycommand\s+(?:-\S+\s+)*"?([^\s"]+(?!\/"))\/?"?.*
```

Any clue how to ignore the characters for extraction which are part of regex group but at specific position (eg the rightmost)?

Comment: You say you want to extract `/path/to/dir` in all cases, but some of them have no leading `/`.

Comment: Why are you using a regex for this at all? Just trim the last character if it's a slash.

Comment: That's absolutely correct. I will also update question with better word.

Comment: If you mean to extract `/path/to/dir` or `path/to/dir` you can use `\S*mycommand\s+(?:-\S+\s+)*(?|"([^"]*?)\/?"|(\S+)(?<!\/)).*`, see https://regex101.com/r/NOQvVk/1

Comment: That's fantastic. meanwhile i try to grasp in debug mode with that link. May I have your answer so that I can accept that?

Comment: If you add a leading / to a relative path you can run into trouble by changing the user intentions, and probably leading to a different file instead.  That's a very dangerous spec.

Comment: The use case is just about bringing consistent way to store dir path, and later use it in some analytics. It's not being shown to users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```php
\S*mycommand\s+(?:-\S+\s+)*(?|"([^"]*?)\/?"|(\S+)(?<!\/)).*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NOQvVk/1). *Details*:

- `\S*` - zero or more non-whitespace chars
- `mycommand` - a literal string
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `(?:-\S+\s+)*` - zero or more occurrences of `-`, one or more non-whitespaces, one or more whitespaces
- `(?|"([^"]*?)\/?"|(\S+)(?<!\/))` - a [branch reset group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/branchreset.html) that matches either:

  - `"([^"]*?)\/?"` - `"`, Group 1 capturing any zero or more chars other than a `"`, as few as possible, and then an optional `/` and a `"` char
  - `|` - or
  - `(\S+)(?<!\/)` - Group 1 (group ID is still `1` as it is inside a branch reset group): one or more whitespaces with no `/` at the end
- `.*` - the rest of the line.

Comment: Just a little flavour of this. What if we want to match directory with real double quotes or even apace as their path. `path/t"o/dir` and also `path/t o/dir`. Now this case get complicated since we have to do internal lookahead/lookaround. Any tip for modified case?

Comment: @codeofnode `path/t"o/dir` is already [matched OK](https://regex101.com/r/NOQvVk/2) with the above regex. `path/t o/dir` MUST be inside double quotes, else, the command line won't be parsed fine anywhere as you need to know where the option starts and ends and without quotes, the boundaries are not clear.

Comment: I was curious about cases when  `"path/t\"o/dir"` and `path/t\ o/dir` and `"path/t o/dir"`

Comment: @codeofnode Something like `\S*mycommand\s+(?:-\S+\s+)*(?|"((?:\\.|[^"\\])*?)\/?"|((?:[^\s\\]|\\.)*)(?<!\/)).*` [would work](https://regex101.com/r/NOQvVk/3) then.

Comment: That's amazing. Now i got trick to manage multiple characters together, that is to sub group them with OR. I was trying my head around using \ and space or d " together but not in negation. Got some learning. Thanks